# TS/JS split part of a string from regex match

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, split, match

In the past, I had this regex:

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

And entered this string:

```
logs/{thing:hi}/{thing:hello}
```

Then I used the following:

```
console.log(string.split(regex).filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 1));
```

To get this result:

```
thing:hi
thing:hello
```

For irrelevant design reasons, I **changed** my regex to:

```
\{.*?\}
```

But now, when using the same test string and split command, it returns only this:

```
/
```

I *want* it to return this:

```
{thing:hi}
{thing:hello}
```

How can I modify the split (or anything else) to do this?

Comment: Why not `match`? `s.match(/{.*?}/g)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `match`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

> The `match()` method retrieves the matches when matching a *string* against a *regular expression*.

If you're only interested in returning the two string matches then it's much simpler than using `split`.

```js
var foo = "logs/{thing:hi}/{thing:hello}";
console.log(foo.match(/{.*?}/g));
```